# Values not being set to User object correctly

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `User` object..

```
class User: NSObject {

    var uid: String!
    var handle: String!
    var name: String!
    var profilePicture: String!
    var gender: String!
    var rooms: [String : AnyObject]!
}
```

.. which has its values set when the user signs up for the app, using the below function to set the values in both Firebase and the `User` object:

```
// Set inital user info to User object & Firebase
func setUserInfo() {

    let userInit = User()
    let userRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").childByAutoId()
    let params = ["fields" : "first_name"]
    let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
    graphRequest.start {
        (urlResponse, requestResult) in

        switch requestResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print("error in graph request:", error)
            break
        case .success(let graphResponse):
            if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {
                print(responseDictionary)

                // Name
                if let name = responseDictionary["first_name"] {
                     userRef.child("name").setValue(name)

                    // Profile pic
                    let facebookID: NSString = (responseDictionary["id"] as! NSString)
                    let profilePic = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(facebookID)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1"
                    userRef.child("profilePicture").setValue(profilePic)

                    // Handle
                    // Also check DB to make sure handle isn't already in use
                    if self.handleTextField.text != nil {
                        if let handle = self.handleTextField.text {
                             userRef.child("handle").setValue(handle)

                            // Gender
                            var gender = ""

                            switch self.genderString {
                            case "male":
                                gender = "male"
                                userRef.child("gender").setValue("male")
                            case "female":
                                gender = "female"
                                userRef.child("gender").setValue("female")
                            default:
                                gender = "other"
                                userRef.child("gender").setValue("other")
                            }

                            // UID
                            if let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
                                userInit.uid = uid
                                userRef.child("uid").setValue(uid)
                                print("uid: \(uid)")
                            }

                            // Set all values to User object
                            userInit.name = name as! String
                            userInit.handle = handle
                            userInit.gender = gender
                            userInit.profilePicture = profilePic

                            self.user.append(userInit)
                            print("name: \(name)")
                            print("handle: \(handle)")
                            print("gender: \(gender)")
                            print("profilePic: \(profilePic)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, all the user info is uploaded to Firebase just fine. However when I try to print the values of the `User` object in the next view controller:

```
let user = [User]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let users = User()
    print("name: \(users.name)")
    print("handle: \(users.handle)")
    print("gender: \(users.gender)")
    print("profilePic: \(users.profilePicture)")
}
```

All are printed as nil. Are the values not getting set to the object, or am I trying to access them wrong?

Comment: You create new class in this line `let users = User()`. You need find place to store the user like some singleton class or root view controller.

Comment: `User()` creates an empty `User` object, what do you expect? Btw: Don't use implicit unwrapped optionals in a custom class as an alibi not to write an initializer. That's pretty dangerous, every carelessly written exclamation mark is an invitation "please crash me".

Comment: I guess you are creating anew object User() and not assigning it any value, so you will get nil for that. Try assigning the value you get from your fireDatabase.

Comment: @vadian - Sir, struct vs class for model (like `User` in above case), what would you prefer ? `without going into detailed conversation`

Comment: @Mr.Bista If you need conformance to `NSObject` protocol (for KVC, `NSCoding` etc.) or reference semantics use a class, otherwise a struct.

Comment: @vadian I got it working with the accepted answer but it seems like it may be a hack-y way of doing it - if you know of a better way than what's suggested in the answer feel free to make a suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that you are creating new empty class object in `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let users = User() //you created new empty object of User Type
    print("name: \(users.name)")
    print("handle: \(users.handle)")
    print("gender: \(users.gender)")
    print("profilePic: \(users.profilePicture)")
}
```

and printing all values will give you nil as it is empty. So way which will work is to pass **userInit** object to second view controller having constant  var myUser

```
var myUser:User!
```

in prepareForSegue from fristViewController to second you can supply user Object so hereby the code for secondVC class will become

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
var myUser:User!
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let users = User() //you created new empty object of User Type
     users = myUser
    print("name: \(users.name)")
    print("handle: \(users.handle)")
    print("gender: \(users.gender)")
    print("profilePic: \(users.profilePicture)")
}
```

Comment: OK this seemed to do it - although I'm still confused with the handling of the object. Now that it's working, I have `var user = [User]()` and `var userInit = User()` as class variables in the setup controller, and the values are set in that function with `self.userInit.name = name` etc. Then, I have `var myUser:User!` as a global variable and set `myUser = self.userInit` in `prepareForSegue`. It works, but it just seems like a convoluted process, is this definitely the correct way to do this?

Comment: var user = [User]() is an Array of User but you have only single object User in var userInit = User() so ideally you can either append user in Array User or create a single var myUser:User! and setting it.Does it make sense now.?